# Combining two looping functions into one

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a class that defines a list and two looping functions that find the items in the list that have some property. Can these two looping functions be combined into one more generic looping function that has the inner Bar.Function() as a parameter?

```
class Foo {
    List<Bar> bar;

    List<int> SomeFunc() {
        List<int> list;
        for (i...) {
           if (bar[i].IsSomething()) {
               list.Add(i);
           }
        }
        return list;
    }


    List<int> SomeOtherFunc() {
        List<int> list;
        for (i...) {
           if (bar[i].IsSomethingElse()) {
               list.Add(i);
           }
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Helping a person refactor his code isn't quite the purpose of stackoverflow. you can try ask it on [`codereview`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @gdoron The asker was looking for a more clean and efficient way to write code and asked the question in a general manner.  I don't see how that violates the purpose of SO.

Comment: Even after reading the rules, I'm not sure I understand why this was closed. JLRishe understood what I was asking perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is easy if you use lambdas:

```
class Foo 
{
        List<Bar> bar;

        List<int> SomeFunc()
        {
            return LoopedTest(b => b.IsSomething());
        }


        List<int> SomeOtherFunc()
        {
            return LoopedTest(b => b.IsSomethingElse());
        }

        private List<int> LoopedTest(Predicate<Bar> test)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < bar.Count; i++)
            {
                if (test(bar[i]))
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

}
```

As others have mentioned, in this particular case, there's already a relatively succinct construct in place for the filtering you're doing (improved with phoog's suggestion):

```
return IEnumerable.Range(0, bar.Count).Where(i => bar[i].IsSomething()).ToList();
```

And you can also combine both of these solutions to get some very clean code:

```
class Foo 
{
        List<Bar> bar;

        List<int> SomeFunc()
        {
            return FindIndexes(b => b.IsSomething());
        }

        List<int> SomeOtherFunc()
        {
            return FindIndexes(b => b.IsSomethingElse());
        }

        private List<int> FindIndexes(Predicate<Bar> test)
        {
            return IEnumerable.Range(0, bar.Count).Where(i => test(bar[i])).ToList();
        }
}
```

Comment: With this solution, you're still looping through the list twice.

Comment: @frenchie I think you missed the point of the question.  The asker is trying to eliminate duplicate code, not apply both conditions at once.

Comment: Another option: `Enumerable.Range(0, bar.Count).Where(i => bar[i].IsSomething()).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks @phoog.  I've incorporated your suggestion into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple LINQ call:

```
 List<int> res = list.Select(x => x.SomeFunc).Union(list.Select(y => y.SomeFunc2))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are after a list of the indices of matches as a precursor to getting a list of the items themselves, you can use Linq:

```
var selection = bar.Where(b => b.IsSomething()).ToList();
```

Since this is just a single statement with Linq, you probably don't need to put it in its own method, but if you did it would look lie this:

```
private List<Bar> SomeFunc(Predicate<Bar> test)
{
    return bar.Where(test).ToList();
}
```

If you are really after the indices, then with Linq it would look like this:

```
var selection = bar.Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
                .Where(x => x.b.IsSomething())
                .Select(x => x.i)
                .ToList();
```

And factored into a method, that would be:

```
private List<Bar> SomeFunc(Predicate<Bar> test)
{
    return bar.Select((b, i) => new { b, i })
                .Where(x => test(x.b))
                .Select(x => x.i)
                .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I don'y think it will work at all.

Comment: This is not the answer: a) there are TWO conditions to check for and b) linq isn't going to be faster than a loop because it adds a little bit of overhead.

Comment: That will return a list of `Bar` not `Int`

Comment: @frenchie It's not clear in the question if they actually want to combine the results, or just refactor out common code. I assumed the latter.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Missed that he wanted indices not the items themselves. Fixed to address that.

Comment: @frenchie I believe you're mistaken.  The user sounds like they want to factor out the common functionality, not combine the two conditions.

Comment: Well look at my answer: it achieve both ends.

Comment: @frenchie No it doesn't.